# Deploy Add in Outlook in Heroku (Yeoman Generator heroku)

Tags: node.js, heroku, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins

Good afternoon, I have generated an Outlook add in with Yeoman, I am about to try to upload it to a Heroku environment, but I don't know what guidelines to follow to upload it well, I have uploaded nodejs projects to heroku before, but changing the port and some script works, I don't know what documentation I should follow.

Best regards

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. SO isn't here to replace search engines, documentation, or tutorials. Assuming this is a web service of some kind, have you searched for documentation on deploying projects in whatever language you used to Heroku? Do you have _specific_ concerns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You deal with a typical web application. There is a command in the scripts section of the `package.json` file if you build the add-in based on the webpack bundler:

```
"build": "webpack --mode production",
```

So, if you run it in the following way:

```
npm run build
```

You will get all the files configured in the `dist` folder. So, you just need to upload them to any web server.

In the `webpack.config.js` you need to configure the production URL to build the add-in correctly and ready for a specific web server. There is no need to change the ports manually. However, you may check the manifest file.

Comment: Thank you very much, this has worked successfully, now I am facing the problem that when I add an angular directive, such as *ngIf or *ngFor, I find that the plugin does not load on the page, if I leave it without any directive if the component loads, do you know anything about this? thank you very much.

Comment: Have no ideas about directives. But I'd suggest creating a new add-in with angular and check how it works with webpack.